# Java Bean Persistence with XMLEncoder

Tags: java, persistence, javabeans

I've written a bean class containing a HashMultiMap (from the Guava library). I would like to XML encode the bean using the JRE's XMLEncoder. Using a custom PersistenceDelegate I've successfully written the bean to file. However, when I attempt to deserialize the XML I get the exception:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <unbound>=HashMultimap.put("pz1", "pz2")`

What am I doing wrong?

```
// create the bean
SomeBean sb = new SomeBean();

// add some data
HashMultimap<String, String> stateMap = HashMultimap.create();    
stateMap.put("pz1", "pz2");
stateMap.put("pz3", "pz4");

sb.setStateMap(stateMap);

// encode as xml 
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("myXMLFile.xml");
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);
encoder.setPersistenceDelegate(HashMultimap.class, new CustomPersistenceDelegate());
encoder.writeObject(sb);

// decode the xml
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("myXMLFile.xml"); 
XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(is);
Object deSerializedObject = decoder.readObject();

class CustomPersistenceDelegate extends DefaultPersistenceDelegate
{
    protected Expression instantiate(Object oldInstance, Encoder out)
    {
        return new Expression(oldInstance, oldInstance.getClass(), "create", null);
    }

    protected void initialize(Class<?> type, Object oldInstance, Object newInstance,
                              Encoder out)
    {
        super.initialize(type, oldInstance, newInstance, out);

        com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap<String, String> m =
            (com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap) oldInstance;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entries())
        {
            out.writeStatement(new Statement(oldInstance, "put", 
            new Object[] { entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() }));
        }

    }
}

public class SomeBean
{
    private HashMultimap<String, String> stateMap;

    public HashMultimap<String, String> getStateMap()
    {
        return stateMap;
    }

    public void setStateMap(HashMultimap<String, String> stateMap)
    {
        this.stateMap = stateMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I took your code, and put it into a Junit test, and had no problem. It worked fine with no Exception. Can you please post the full StackTrace?  See [here](http://txtup.net/Lndut)

Comment: Sam I don't get a full stack trace. Instead, the debug window shows the following: java.lang.Exception: Encoder: discarding statement HashMultimap.put("pz3", "pz4");
Continuing ...
java.lang.Exception: Encoder: discarding statement HashMultimap.put("pz1", "pz2");
Continuing ...
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <unbound>=HashMultimap.put("pz3", "pz4");
Continuing ...
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <unbound>=HashMultimap.put("pz1", "pz2");
Continuing ...

Comment: Sam were you able to decode the object? The map is empty when I decode it.

Comment: Yes - it decoded fine.  I posted the unit test code as a link in my first comment. If you look at the unit test, it makes assertions that the map contains "pz3" and "pz3" which are successful.  I'm guessing that you have some kind of a Classpath problem which is loading the wrong version of the Hashmultimap.  More questions: 1) what IDE are you using?  2) did you try running from the command line, and do you get same error. (try running the unit test I posted from command line).

Comment: 1) I'm using NetBeans 7.3. 2) Yes. Same error. Steps taken: i) javac -cp guava-14.0.1.jar;junit-4.10.jar;. XmlEncoderTest.java ii) java -cp guava-14.0.1.jar;junit-4.10.jar;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore XmlEncoderTest iii) There was 1 failure:
1) testEncoding(XmlEncoderTest)

Comment: Sam using JRE 6 the unit test passes. With JRE 7 it fails. Can you confirm you are running JRE 6?

Comment: I ran it in Eclipse using jdk1.7.0_02. I'm going to double check the command line behavior using JDK 7 and JRE7.

Comment: It fails with JRE7 but not JDK7. I will see if I can track that down.

Comment: Well, I've tracked it down to the following: Java 7 version build 2 doesn't have this problem. The versions which do have this problem are Java 7 build 15 and higher. The issue appears to be that the MethodFinder class (com.sun.beans.finder.MethodFinder) sees the method signature in HashMultimap as put(Object,Object) and it can't match the signature using the string arguments.

Comment: After some additional testing, I've determined the issue was introduced in Java 7 build 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a solution (yet). But here is something which at least clarifies the problem. It seems that some change made in Java 7 build 15 and higher has broken the method look up that your Statement requires.  If you add an ExceptionListener to the XmlEncoder, it gives you a better idea of how this is failing:

```
        encoder.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
        @Override
        public void exceptionThrown(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("got exception. e=" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

You will see a full stacktrace then:

```
java.lang.Exception: Encoder: discarding statement HashMultimap.put(Object, Object);
at java.beans.Encoder.writeStatement(Encoder.java:306)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeStatement(XMLEncoder.java:400)
at test2.XmlEncoderTest$CustomPersistenceDelegate.initialize(XmlEncoderTest.java:83)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:118)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:327)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:330)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:454)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:115)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:327)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:330)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:454)
at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:194)
at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:253)
at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:400)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:118)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:327)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:330)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:454)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:115)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:327)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject1(Encoder.java:258)
at java.beans.Encoder.cloneStatement(Encoder.java:271)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeStatement(Encoder.java:301)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeStatement(XMLEncoder.java:400)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:330)

    ...

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: HashMultimap.put(Object, Object);
    at java.beans.Statement.invokeInternal(Statement.java:313)
    at java.beans.Statement.access$000(Statement.java:58)
    at java.beans.Statement$2.run(Statement.java:185)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.beans.Statement.invoke(Statement.java:182)
    at java.beans.Statement.execute(Statement.java:173)
    at java.beans.Encoder.writeStatement(Encoder.java:304)
    ... 51 more
```

The *Caused by* section shows that it failed to locate the *put* method. It looks to me like this happens because it can't match the method signature properly any more. It fails in the java beans MethodFinder, but since the source code is not included in JDK, I couldn't track it down well enough.

If I can find exact cause, I will update this.  Just wanted to provide you with more information in the meantime.

**UPDATE**

I think it's a bug in these later versions.  Here is a unit test which exposes the bug (or unexpected behavior) more directly.  The failure below is exactly what is happening in your code:

```
@Test
public void testMethodFinder() throws Exception {

    Method m0 = MethodFinder.findMethod(this.getClass(), "setUp", new Class<?>[0]);
    assertNotNull(m0);

    // this is okay, because method is declared in the type referenced
    Method m = MethodFinder.findMethod(Multimap.class, "put", new Class<?>[] { Object.class, Object.class });
    assertNotNull(m);

    try {
        // this fails, apparently because method is not declared in this subclass (is inherited from parent class)
        Method m2 = MethodFinder.findMethod(HashMultimap.class, "put", new Class<?>[] { Object.class, Object.class });
        assertNotNull(m2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("got exception. e=" + e);
    }
}
```